# parMapN that finishes even when one program encounters an error

Tags: scala, scala-cats, io-monad

Using `parMapN`, multiple `IO`s can be executed in parallel, like this:

```scala
import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect.{ContextShift, IO}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

val ioA = IO(for(i <- 1 to 100) { println(s"A$i"); Thread.sleep(100) })
val ioB = IO(for(i <- 1 to 100) { println(s"B$i"); Thread.sleep(100) })
val ioC = IO(for(i <- 1 to 100) { println(s"C$i"); Thread.sleep(100) })

val program = (ioA, ioB, ioC).parMapN { (_, _, _) => () }

program.unsafeRunSync()
```

Sample output:

```scala
A1
C1
B1
A2
C2
B2
A3
C3
B3
A4
C4
B4
A5
B5
C5
A6
B6
C6
A7
B7
C7
A8
...
```

According to the [documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/io.html#parmapn), unfinished tasks get cancelled if  any of the `IO`s completes with a failure. What is the best way of changing this mechanism, so that all `IO`s are finishing anyway?

In my case some of the `IO`s do not return anything (`IO[Unit]`) and I still want to make sure everything runs until it is finished or encounters an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found one possible answer shortly after posting my question. Not sure if it is the best way to handle this, but defining my `IO`s like this works for me:

```scala
val ioA = IO(for(i <- 1 to 100) { println(s"A$i"); Thread.sleep(100) }).attempt
val ioB = IO(for(i <- 1 to 100) { println(s"B$i"); Thread.sleep(100) }).attempt
val ioC = IO(for(i <- 1 to 100) { println(s"C$i"); Thread.sleep(100) }).attempt
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I noticed there is nothing raising any error on your example code.
So you should have a code like the bellow one to be able to see this feature:

```
val ioA = IO(for(i <- 1 to 100) { println(s"A$i"); Thread.sleep(100) })
val ioB = IO.raiseError[Unit](new Exception("boom"))
val ioC = IO(for(i <- 1 to 100) { println(s"C$i"); Thread.sleep(100) })
```

Also it looks not so good since the `attempt` function will change the internal structure to an `IO[Either[_,_]]` which does not appear your intention, does it?